# Base-64 illegal string when using SessionAuthenticationModule with Asp.Net WIF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth

In my application I am letting the user sign into dropbox and when the process is done it write the claims to the fedauth cookie using the SessionAuthenticationModule.

```
    var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
    if (sam != null)
    {

       // (ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).AddClaim(new Claim("Provider", "Dropbox"));

        var cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim("Provider", "Dropbox") }, "OAuth"));

        var transformer = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.ClaimsAuthenticationManager;
        if (transformer != null)
        {

            cp = transformer.Authenticate(String.Empty, cp);
        }
        var token = new SessionSecurityToken(cp);
        sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);                       

    }
```

The claims are written and when new requests are made the user are authenticated and claims are working.

My problem is, if the users starts an authentication process with Azure ACS by navigating to one of the login urls in:

```
https://s-innovations.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/metadata/identityProviders.js?protocol=wsfederation&realm=http://77.75.160.102:2638/&version=1.0&callback=ShowSigninPage
```

i get an exception when the STS returns to my site:

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. 

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. ]
   System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength) +10545309
   System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength) +130
   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +41
   System.IdentityModel.Services.ChunkedCookieHandler.ReadInternal(String name, HttpCookieCollection requestCookies) +350
   System.IdentityModel.Services.ChunkedCookieHandler.ReadCore(String name, HttpContext context) +45
   System.IdentityModel.Services.CookieHandler.Read(String name, HttpContext context) +74
   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken& sessionToken) +126
   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +116
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

If the process is reversed, logging in by Azure ACS first and then dropbox. things works fine. Dropbox claims are overwriting the Azure ACS claims. This lead me to think that i have an error in the codesnippet at the start where i use SAM to write the cookie?

**Update**

I just found out that when not using MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler it works.

```
  <securityTokenHandlers>
    <!--<add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />-->
    <!--<remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />-->
  </securityTokenHandlers>
```

Any idea how to change my code to support the MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the cookie gets truncated. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome. I could see the cookie and i can decode it myself using base64 to get the inner cookie.

Comment: This can be quite possible due to the cookie size this guy had same issue as well.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752434/getting-not-a-valid-base-64-string-on-federated-identity-token

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SessionAuthenticationModule` to create your `SessionSecurityToken`:

```
var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;

var token = sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken(
    claimsPrincipal, 
    "application-context", 
    DateTime.UtcNow, 
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1), 
    true);

sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);
```